# Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime

I am trying to pull the data out from mssql server table to print html table in webpage using php, the data i am pulling down is "DateTime " column and when i run the script i got error message saying " Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string "

and the below is my script. can anyone point me correct way? Thank you so much in advance.

```
$sql = "SELECT  DateCreated FROM Item WHERE Inactive = '0' ";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}


while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
   $html_table = '<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">';
  $html_table .= '<tr><td width="100" align="center">' .$row['DateCreated'].'</td></tr>';

$html_table .= '</table>'; 
echo $html_table;  


}
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted the relevant part of the code?

Comment: Do a `var_dump()` instead to find out the exact type of the variable.

Comment: Thought of something else to check... are you sure that Inactive is not a datetime field.  That could also produce that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be like this to have the SQL Engine itself return a string value in your first line of code.  *There might be more performat ways to convert on the PHP end but I'm not as good with that side of the work.*

```
$sql = "SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), DateCreated, 101) AS DateCreatedString 
FROM Item WHERE Inactive = '0' ";
```

There are a lot of other date format standards you can modify with the third parameter found in [this guide from microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).  The 101 that I used gives the date back in mm/dd/yyyy format, but literally every format under the sun including times, months names, centuries, milliseconds etc. can be returned by using one of the other codes.